# I want to know if my ram is ok for Ubuntu

Tags: ram, versions

Hi i have a amd64 2800mz procresor with 256MiB RAM, what Ubuntu can install to run smoothly?.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not enough RAM, it doesn't even meet the minimum required (512MiB RAM) to run Ubuntu (11.XX and higher versions).

You can go ahead and try to install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) instead which its been said to run on a 256MiB minimum but i doubt it would run at all and if it does it wont be even near to "smooth".